# Campos de pais,provincia, etc. han desaparecido del registro de prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, prestashop, prestashop1.7

Hola os escribo porque este problema me trae de cabeza. En prestashop en la sección de ubicaciones geograficas, si nos dirigimos a pais y luego despues de seleccionar el deseado accedemos a sus opciones hay un textarea que permite añadirle los nombres que hacen referencia a la base de datos. Como se ve en la foto de abajo. Estos datos aparecen en el formulario de registro cuando un usuario crea su cuenta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por algun extraño motivo que desconozco, en el formulario de registro ya no aparece ningún campo de los que salen en la foto es decir ha desaparecido todo. Me gustaría que se visualizara de nuevo pero no se que puede estar fallando.

He comprobado los datos de transporte y de pago y aparentemente están bien, he probado a desactivar el pais y volver a activarlo, también he borrado todos los campos apareciendome un error porque se requieren los campos obligatorios a lo que yo volvi a colocarlos como estaban y guardé.

Ya no se que mas intentar he buscado información en internet pero no encuentro nada relacionado con que a alguien le haya desaparecido como a mi.

Por lo tanto si sabeis como se desactivan estos campos y me podeis decir a modo que pruebe de activarlos nuevamente, o si a alguien le ha pasado lo mismo y sabe solucionarlo, estaría muy agradecida!

Todavia no he encontrado la solución a esto, alguna ayuda?

Comment: Si tienes acceso a la base de datos, consulta el valor del campo 'format' en la tabla ps_address_format, para el id_country = 6 (España). Si no está vacío y el valor tiene buena pinta (campos de dirección), entonces se te tiene que haber fastidiado el PrestaShop por algún otro lado. Tendrás que recapacitar, qué has hecho recientemente, qué módulo has instalado o quitado, si has aplicado actualización... Pueden ser muchas cosas.

Comment: Aparentemente tiene aspecto similar, he comprobado y ambos campos estan rellenados de  la misma forma, la cuestion fue que desde que desaparecio, el unico cambio fue  nivel de ajustes desde el mismo prestashop, es decir el tipico cambio de activar desctivar opciones, tal vez algo de este pueda estar afectando pero desconozco si podria ser algo concreto ya que no solo lo toque yo, por desgracia, hay alguna configuracion que haga desparecer esto?.

Comment: Que haga desaparecer todo no, no hay ninguna opción de configuración para eso.

Comment: mmm debería revisar algun archivo para poder reestablecer estos campos? Desconozco cual archivo debería mostrarlo en el formulario de registro, yo revisé lo que crei adecuado pero sin certeza de estr viendo el archivo correcto. Por si lo puedo arreglar de form manual